# Linear system with Kronecker products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $L \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix and let $I_n \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be the  identity matrix. Consider the linear system
$$
(L \otimes I_n + I_n \otimes L)x = a \otimes b,
$$
for $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ and where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. Does there exist a formula, in terms of a series expansion that does not require the eigenpairs of $L$, for the solution to this equation?

I am confronted to a problem where I need to solve this system numerically, and where $n$ is too large to calculate the eigenpairs of $L$. What is accessible at a reasonable numerical cost is the solution to linear systems of the form $L y = c$.